# I am trying to create a DAO and Unable to execute proposal after successfful queuing of it through timelock contract

Tags: blockchain, dao, governance, timelock

here is the error i am getting in the console "underlying transaction reverted".
[image: error image]

Comment: Whats contracts are you using? Can you share the error message as text?

Comment: Without knowing the source code, it will be hard to help out here since the problem scope could be very big